# how to approach a QSpinbox in other widgets?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, qspinbox

I'm using Qt-desiger to make a GUI.
For example I have a QSpinbox in a QCombobox in a Groubbox.
How can i use `SetValue` for my Spinbox?
how i have to "describe" the way to my Spinbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets inside other Widgets do not create hierarchy in Qt, it means that if you have `widget1` inside `widget2` you can directly access the `widget1`, like `self.widget1` (and `self.widget2`)

You can create a class which will contain all your widgets on your ui form as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import uic
Form, Base = uic.loadUiType(r'path\to\your\uifile.ui') #get ui Form and Base class
class Window(Form, Base):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        #here you can access your widgets
        #self.combobox.addItem('Item')
        #self.spinbox.setValue(10)
        ...
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to use `pyuic` to generate a python module from the designer `ui` file:

```
pyuic4 -o mainwindow_ui.py mainwindow.ui
```

Then import it into your application:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will add all the widgets from Qt Designer, and make them attributes of the `MainWindow` class. The attribute names will be the same as the `objectName` property that was set in Qt Designer. So if the QComboBox was named "comboBox", and the QSpinBox named "spinBox", they could be accessed within the `MainWindow` class like this:

```
    self.comboBox.addItems('Foo')
    self.spinBox.setValue(10)
```